# How to get the client system UUID in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, operating-system

I want to get the client system UUID in angular (v14) project. When I ran the below command I'm getting my system UUID, the same UUID I want to retrieve from the angular project.

```
wmic csproduct get uuid
```

I tried multiple libraries but all of them are generating some random UUID. But I need constant unique (UUID) Id. Any help much appreciated.

If that's not possible with angular, is there any alternatives possible? I need one constant and unique Id for each client system.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: do you expect to run your angular application in the browser of some user?

Comment: yes @Andrei, I will deploy my angular project over the internet and users can use it.

Comment: you don't have access to operating system from the javascript in browser application. only browser apis and javascript things are available. I would advice you to generate random UUID, store it in `localStorage`, and use it as some indentifyer for the particular client. All the other ways would be simmilar and really depend on your case

Comment: but If the localStorage is cleared by another applications, then I will lost the UUID right? @Andrei

Comment: you have one localstorage for every domain. so if yoursite.com puts something in localstorage, most likely it will be there for pretty long

Comment: Yes, that is fine @Andrei ,but if we set localStorage value in chrome browser and next time if the user access the site from another browser like microsoft edge or brave browser, then we can not access the UUID from localStorage? is this valid scenario?

Comment: yes, that is true. but there is no way to store something in that scenario

Comment: If you want to save data so a user has access to it anywhere you have to use a real database and connect to it.  There's just no way around that.